# Cannot translate title set in the layout XML magento 1

Tags: magento-1, xml, title, translate

this is my layout xml for the checkout success page:

```
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <remove name="checkout.success"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setData" translate="title"><key>title</key><value>Success Order</value></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="content_text">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>succes-checkout</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

I want to translate the word: `Success Order`. So I went to my theme/locale/de_DE/translate.csv which is set in the locale and I added this:

```
"Mage_Checkout::Success Order","sdadsa"
"Mage_Page::Success Order","sdadsa"
"Success Order","sdadsa"
```

None of them is working. I cleared the cache , so its not a cache issue :) Any idea why this is not working ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translate` should use a valid node

change

```
 <action method="setData" translate="title"><key>title</key><value>Success Order</value></action>
```

to

```
 <action method="setData" translate="value"><key>title</key><value>Success Order</value></action>
```

You can add `module="my_module"` to use translation from your extension.

---

Shorter:

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Success Order</title></action>
```

Comment: nice observation I didn't notice that. thx :)

Comment: Besides this feed back you could also specify a module so you can translate based on Module as you did in your example. You can do that like this ``<reference name="head"><action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action></reference>``